# making multiple week long back to back reservations for a hotel with the intention of canceling all but one of them

Tags: bookings, hotels, cancellations, california, yosemite

The premiere hotel in Yosemite is the Ahwahnee Hotel and, if you want to stay there in the summer, you generally need to book it a year in advance.

The premiere hike in Yosemite is Half Dome. The last 400 ft of Half Dome consist of a cable system that you can only do if you have a permit and you get a permit by applying for a lottery in April of that year. Since the cables usually come down in October that means that the longest lead time you could possibly have is about six months.

So, basically, if you want to do both on the same trip, you have to book the Ahwahnee hotel blind. Which I did and I lost so now I've canceled my Ahwahnee hotel reservation.

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to maximize my odds for next year. One strategy that's occurred to me is making 12 back to back week long bookings at the Ahwahnee. That'd be 12 distinct bookings vs one 12 week long booking. Then, when applying for the half dome lottery, instead of giving them a window of one week I'd give them a window of 12 weeks. If I win the lottery I'd then cancel all but one of my 12 reservations, keeping the one reservation that overlaps with my Half Dome permit. If I don't win the lottery at all I'd cancel all the reservations.

In order to make a reservation at the Ahwahnee you need a deposit. "*First night stay plus taxes and fees are due at the time of booking*" The website says. The website further says "*Cancellations made 7 or more days prior to arrival will receive a full refund*". So making 12x distinct reservations is gonna cost a pretty penny. For me my deposit was about $700 so for 12x back to back reservations that'd be a little over $8,000. And sure, I'd get almost all of that money back but that's a lot of money (6 months minimum) and a fairly lengthy amount of time to essentially just sit in escrow. That, in and of itself, is kinda a reason not to pursue this strategy but are there other reasons not to pursue this strategy? Could the hotel blacklist me? Does the hotel have a leg to stand on it they decided to not refund my multiple deposits?

It has been suggested to me that I might be able to just do the hike anyway, even without a permit. Like maybe a group might have some dropouts and they might be open to letting me use one of their dropouts permits. But this question isn't about the merits of those alternative strategies - its about the merit of the strategy I proposed.

Comment: I believe the official term for what you're suggesting is "A Dick Move"

Comment: Perhaps you could ask the hotel. They might be quite happy with that arrangement, or they might tell you up front they'll cancel everything, or they might have a better solution you haven't thought of (you won't be the first to think of this).

Comment: @GregHewgill Why would a hotel be happy to take 11+ bookings that it knows will be cancelled when it could instead make those rooms available for others who will actually use them?  If they weren't sold out most of the year it might be different - but they are which is exactly why neubert has come up with this idea in the first place!

Comment: If this is the premiere hotel, that means that there are others, possibly having more options for booking. Why not consider all of them, and make the booking in available ones if you win the lottery?

Answer (score 3):

> ... but are there other reasons not to pursue this strategy?

It's ethically questionable but beauty is in the eyes of the beholder. The more tangible consequence would be that the hotel becomes aware of it and just cancels all your reservations.

> Could the hotel blacklist me?

They sure can. A business can freely choose who to do business with (unless they are in a protected class) and can deny you for whatever reason. In this case that's quite possible to happen.

> Does the hotel have a leg to stand on it they decided to not refund my multiple deposits?

Probably not. It's more likely that they just cancel all of your reservations, refund you the money and decline any further business.

Comment: (+1) Given the lottery situation the OP describes, they’re probably not the first to have thought of this ‘solution’ and the hotel may well be alert to and have a process to detect such bookings

Comment: Or they may allow it and charge the high booking cost because of it.